# Вывод элементов таксономий перед основным содержанием каталога в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

В каталоге продуктов есть обычное разбиение по категориям (создана таксономия "Категории"), например стулья, диваны, кровати и т.д. Но некоторые товары входят в так называемые коллекции, для которых создана отдельная таксономия "Коллекции".

В коллекции входит только один тип товаров - например несколько стульев. Диван и стул не могут быть вместе в коллекции (по сути в коллекцию входит один и тот же товар, просто разных расцветок).

Задача при переходе в любую категорию вывести сначала все имеющиеся в ней коллекции, с их заголовком. А затем все оставшиеся товары, при этом не нарушая пагинацию.

Comment: Не нарушая пагинацию - ничего не выйдет. Это разные запросы к базе, а пагинация считает только один запрос. Ну то есть все можно, конечно. Надо объединять результаты трех запросов в один, а потом по ним делать цикл, да еще все это запихнуть в WooCommerce. Непростая задачка, не для короткого ответа здесь.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Реализовано без WooCommerce, забыл указать.

Comment: Немногим легче.